# Execute operating system command in Java - Doesn't work when I want run backup of postgres DB

Tags: java, postgresql

I try to exec a command line program from Java (in order to backup my postgres DB), but it doesn't work.

The method that exec the command works with other example (for example dir command) and also the string I use to backup the DB works if I use it in dos prompt windows. Nevertheless, when I use that string in that method, it doesn't work.

Java method to execute the command:

```
public static boolean ExecuteDOSCommand( String[] dosCommand_Array_Arg )    {
        final String posizione_per_log = "ExecuteDOSCommand()";
        boolean result=false;
        try {

            //_________________________________________________
            String dosCommand ="";
            for(int i = 0; i < dosCommand_Array_Arg.length; i++){
                dosCommand=dosCommand + dosCommand_Array_Arg[i];
            }

            //_________________________________________________
            //Esegue il comando DOS 
            LogManager.log_info(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Eseguo Comando DOS:     " + dosCommand );
            Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process myProcess = myRuntime.exec(dosCommand);

            //_________________________________________________
            final InputStream in = myProcess.getInputStream();
            int ch;
            while((ch = in.read()) != -1)  {
                //LogManager.log_debug(myClassName, posizione_per_log, ch );
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }



            //_________________________________________________
            int resultProcess = myProcess.waitFor();
   LogManager.log_debug_FAU(myClassName, posizione_per_log, " resultProcess _____" + resultProcess + "____   ");

            if(resultProcess == 0){ //0= tutto OK
                result=true;
                LogManager.log_info(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Comando DOS eseguito con successo ");
            }
            else{
                result=false;
                LogManager.log_warn(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Attenzione! Comando DOS NON effettuato  " );

                // get the error stream of the process and print it
                InputStream myErrorStream = myProcess.getErrorStream();
                for (int i = 0; i < myErrorStream.available(); i++) {
                    LogManager.log_debug(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Errore:  " + myErrorStream.read());
                }                

            }
            //_________________________________________________

        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            result=false;
            LogManager.log_warn(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Attenzione! Comando DOS NON effettuato  " );
            LogManager.log_error(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "IOException " + ex.getMessage(), null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result=false;
            LogManager.log_warn(myClassName, posizione_per_log, "Attenzione! Comando DOS NON effettuato  " );
            LogManager.log_error_Exception(myClassName, posizione_per_log, ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Java code used to run my desired backup:

```
    final String[] cmd_Array = {
        "\"" + pathAssoluto_Dump + StringsNomi_File_e_Dir.NOMEFILE_Default_pg_dump + "\"",
        "  -h " + ipAddress_DbServer_Used_String,
        "  -p " + Parameters.DB_Port,
        "  -U " + Parameters.DB_Username,
        "  -F " + "c", 
        "  -v " , 
        "  " + Parameters.DB_Name, 
        "  > ",
        "\"" + pathAssoluto_DirBackupDB + nome_FileBackupDB + "\" "  
    };    


    final String[] cmd_Test = {
        " cmd /c dir  " ,
        "\"" + "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL"  + "\""  
    };            


    result=Utilities_NoAndroid.ExecuteDOSCommand(cmd_Array);
```

If I put as argument of the method "cmd_Test", it works.
If I use "cmd_Array" it doesn't work.

Note that the print out in log of the command is:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_dump.exe"  -h 192.168.1.6  -p 5432  -U postgres  -F c  -v   iptetra  > "C:/_OutputETIP/MainServer/BackupDB/2016-06-10_10-18-14_backupDB.backup"
```

If I copy this string and paste it in command prompt of windows, it works, so it shouldn't be an error in dos command.
Note also that I put double quote in path, because tha path contains spaces, otherwise it doesn't work for sure.

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it work if you do not include the redirect of the output to a file?

Comment: check paths, user rights

Comment: Don't say DOS, say "command line". This topic has nothing to DOS

Comment: `dosCommand=dosCommand + " " + dosCommand_Array_Arg[i];` or such. **ProcessBuilder** easier.

Comment: Very surprised that the command works unchanged when pasted into a command prompt box of windows.  You're using forward slashes in the path to pg_dump, instead of backslashes.

Comment: @StephaneM  - I tried to not include the redirect output to a file. What happen is that I don't get any result. I mean that I don't get any value for "resultProcess", so it seems that the waitFor() never get the result. What does it mean?

Comment: @Gary   I'm sure it works also with forward slashs in command line. I read somewhere that forward works everywhere, while back only in windows, that's why I use forward.

Comment: @Joop Eggen   ; I didn't understand your suggestion, can you explain more, please?

Comment: (1) Between the args a space must be reinserted. (2) ProcessBuilder is a later class that does a bit more encapsulation (threading troubles & out, in, err). (Additionally) JDBC could be used too - using PostgreSQL's [backup procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html): should be tested with an SQL client, and then hard-coded in JDBC.

Comment: Hi, I tried with back slashes, I tried adding spaces (but they were already present), I tried with processbuilder, but nothing to do: I continue to get a long list of errors (they are simply numbers, got by the row "System.out.print((char)ch);"   , so they don't have any sense to me...).
Anyone else that have an idea?